# Execute bash command in Node.js and get exit code

Tags: node.js, bash, exit-code

I can run a bash command in node.js like so:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("ls -la", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

How do I get the exit code of that command (`ls -la` in this example)? I've tried running

```
exec("ls -la", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  exec("echo $?", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
  });
});
```

This somehow always returns 0 regardless of the the exit code of the previous command though. What am I missing?

Comment: your first example is already giving you the stdout in the console.log

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Those 2 commands are running in separate shells.

To get the code, you should be able to check `err.code` in your callback.

If that doesn't work, you need to add an `exit` event handler

e.g.

```
dir = exec("ls -la", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) {
    // should have err.code here?  
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});

dir.on('exit', function (code) {
  // exit code is code
});
```

Comment: Awesome! The `exit` event handler works great; `err.code` only returns a number if the error code is not 0.

Comment: Also `execSync(command[, options])` for those interested in the synchronous version. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

Answer (score 10):

From the docs:

> If a `callback` function is provided, it is called with the arguments `(error, stdout, stderr)`. On success, `error` will be `null`. On error, `error` will be an instance of Error. The `error.code` property will be the exit code of the child process while `error.signal` will be set to the signal that terminated the process. Any exit code other than 0 is considered to be an error.

So:

```
exec('...', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
  }
});
```

Should work.

Answer (score 6):

**`child_process.spawnSync()`**

This function exposes the nicest sync interface: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const child_process = require('child_process');
let out;

out = child_process.spawnSync('true');
console.log('status: ' + out.status);
console.log('stdout: ' + out.stdout.toString('utf8'));
console.log('stderr: ' + out.stderr.toString('utf8'));
console.log();

out = child_process.spawnSync('false');
console.log('status: ' + out.status);
console.log('stdout: ' + out.stdout.toString('utf8'));
console.log('stderr: ' + out.stderr.toString('utf8'));
console.log();

out = child_process.spawnSync('echo', ['abc']);
console.log('status: ' + out.status);
console.log('stdout: ' + out.stdout.toString('utf8'));
console.log('stderr: ' + out.stderr.toString('utf8'));
console.log();
```

Output:

```
status: 0
stdout: 
stderr: 

status: 1
stdout: 
stderr: 

status: 0
stdout: abc

stderr:
```

Tested in Node.js v10.15.1, Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for an `await`/`Promise` version:

```
const exec = require('util').promisify(require('child_process').exec);

let out = await exec(`echo hello`).catch(e => e);

console.log(out.stdout); // outputs "hello"
console.log(out.code); // Note: `out.code` is *undefined* if successful (instead of 0).
```

If the command is successful, then the it'll output an object like `{stderr, stdout}`. If it has a non-zero exit code, then it'll output an error object with `{stderr, stdout, code, killed, signal, cmd}` and the usual JavaScript `Error` object properties like `message` and `stack`.

Answer (score 1):

In node documentation i found this information for the callback function:

On success, error will be null. On error, error will be an instance of Error. **The error.code property will be the exit code of the child process** while error.signal will be set to the signal that terminated the process. Any exit code other than 0 is considered to be an error.