# communicate between python script on server side and javascript in the web-browser

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, socket.io

I have a python script which resides on a web-server (running node.js) and does some machine learning computation. The data has to be supplied to the python script using javascript running in web-browser. How can this be done? I want to know the complete setup. For now, the server is the localhost only.

Comment: One way to do it is to have your browser-side JavaScript send over the data to your server through an API. And then have your server-side JavaScript call the Python script and pass in the data as if it were a Bash command [by using exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732331/execute-bash-command-in-node-js-and-get-exit-code).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `zerorpc`, a socket server and client for both Python and Node.js.

Installing on Python:

```
pip install zerorpc
```

Installing on Node:

```
npm install zerorpc
```

Python server file:

```
import zerorpc

class HelloRPC(object):
   def hello(self, name):

      print "message from host: %s" % name

      return raw_input("Enter your message: ") 

s = zerorpc.Server(HelloRPC())
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")
s.run()
```

Node.js client file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var zerorpc = require("zerorpc");

var client = new zerorpc.Client();
client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
  client.invoke("hello", "RPC", function(error, res, more) {
  console.log(res);
  res.send(req.body.name);
  });

});

app.listen(8080, function() {
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});
```

While the example code here is relatively simple, it should get you started. The overall logic of this setup is as follows:

1. Use express to get data from webpage (stored as `req.body.name`)
2. Take this data and send it via `zerorpc` to your Python server, which can process the data and send it back to the Node.js `zerorpc` client.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a simple API on the server which accept input from the client which can be done via JavaScript.

There are several technologies you could have a look at:

- Ajax.
- WebSockets.